# redirect from one domain to another domain in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have existing application which was deployed on https://demo.com/help and now I want to change the domain to https://example.com.

How can I perform redirection?

I tried below ways;

```
async redirects() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/help',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'host',
          value: '.*\\..*\\..*'
        },
      ],
      permanent: false,
      destination: 'https://example.com'
    }
  ]
},
```

I have added above code in next.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `basePath: false`.

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/help',
        destination: 'https://example.com',
        permanent: false,
        basePath: false
      },
    ]
  },
```